# mysqldump issues with DreamHost

Tags: mysqldump

**Background**:

- I sought to rename a database on [Dreamhost](http://www.dreamhost.com/) web hosting VPS account.
- I also wanted to rename a database user for the database to be created above.
- I followed the approached detailed at [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/195221/how-to-rename-a-mysql-database)
- I used mysqldump to create a backup of the old database (<1MB) as a *.sql file.
- I created a new database with a desired name within the DreamHost CPanel.
- I created a new database user within the DreamHost CPanel (not via the linux command console) to have access to the new database.
- I imported (via linux command console) the *.sql (from mysqldump) as the new desired database.
- I did not drop the old database - as I wanted to be sure that everything was alright before I drop the old database (and edit related scripts pointing to that old database).

Yet upon checking my DreamHost CPanel,

- the size of the new database was not recognised.
- the new database user had access to the new database as expected (this was tested via phpMyAdmin).

Furthermore

- As expected phpMyAdmin does not show me the new database when I logged in with old user details.
- As expected phpMyAdmin recognises the new database when I logged in with the new user details.
- phpMyAdmin recognises the size of the new database.
- phpMyAdmin shows that there is difference in size between the old and new database (I thought this is supposed to be the same size since its a backup).
- I briefly checked the database structure (in phpMyAdmin) and noticed that the difference is coming from the table property “column” known as “Overhead”.
- The Old database has Overheads in a few tables while the mysqldump file does not have any overheads.

**Question**:

1. How come the difference in size
2. Home come the DreamHost CPanel reports that size is unavailable
3. What does Overhead even mean

Any help would be appreciated